# Programmatically Disable Highlight on Click of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

There must be a way to do this, but I can't find it. I have a button I have created programmatically:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(25, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 200, 350);
[button setTitle:@"Inbox" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

All I want is for the button not to highlight or change in appearance in any way when it is touched.  So far I have tried the following when creating the button:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

AND

```
[button setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

AND

```
[button setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
```

AND

```
button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Then in the button action I tried:

```
[sender setHighlighted:!sender.isHighlighted];
```

AND

```
[sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];
```

None of these work.

Comment: Have you looked at showsTouchWhenHighlighted?

Comment: Thanks, just tried it, doesn't work either! I just added it to my list of things I've tried.

Comment: How about `[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateSelected];` or `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make your UIButton a custom button and then apply a UIImage background to it. It won't highlight or change when pressed

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Answer (score 13):

You can just simply set adjustImageWhenHighlighted to No.

```
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Comment: Great answer! 2 more characters

Comment: Great answer i was look from two days for this

Answer (score 6):

Bro, I've tried different ways as you.
But finally have found my own recipe:

I don't know how it works with a custom button with UIImage on it
but for a simple UIButton with the text for a heighlighted state You should simply set the same settings as you have in the default state.

And for *highlighted* state for image property in IB set a whitespace.
You may found that sometimes button might have a strange little offset when you click on it. For that case, remove the text from textField for highlighted state. It will resolve this issue.

[image]

Then on your click event you will see no blinks at all.

Comment: This is a hackish solution.

Comment: This is a hackish solution which works on Xcode 6.2 beta 5 in swift. Nothing not hackish "normal" worked. You just saved my day & night. Gj

Answer (score 0):

For those using a custom PNG image with tint colour switched on, you can avoid the dimming (e.g. from white to grey) with this code:

```
 clearButton.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```