# Disable UIButton highlighting in Storyboard and Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I am trying to disable Highlighting on a UIButton setup in Storyboard. I am using Swift on Xcode 7.1. I have the button set to Custom, and I have tried everything I can think of, and it is still highlighting. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580180/programmatically-disable-highlight-on-click-of-uibutton) is another question for Objective-C, and I have tried everything on it, even the Storyboard image name white space idea.

The button is hooked up correctly.

How do you disable highlighting? Is it a bug in Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean you don't want the button to appear to change when it's tapped. One way to do it is by creating a subclass of `UIButton` that refuses to become highlighted:

```
class NonHighlightingButton: UIButton {
    override var highlighted: Bool {
        set { }
        get { return super.highlighted }
    }
}
```

Then, in your storyboard, set the custom class of your button to `NonHighlightingButton`:

[image: Identity inspector]

Comment: Works for now... I wish i knew why everything else does not work. Thanks.